# Creating a more informative table output

Tags: r, data.table, reshape, mean

I have a data.table as follows

```
panelID = c(1:50)   
year= c(2001:2010)
country = c("NLD", "BEL", "GER")
urban = c("A", "B", "C")
indust = c("D", "E", "F")
sizes = c(1,2,3,4,5)
n <- 2
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)
DT <- data.table(panelID = rep(sample(panelID), each = n),
                 country = rep(sample(country, length(panelID), replace = T), each = n),
                 year = c(replicate(length(panelID), sample(year, n))),
                 some_NA = sample(0:5, 6),                                             
                 some_NA_factor = sample(0:5, 6), 
                 industry = rep(sample(indust, length(panelID), replace = T), each = n),
                 urbanisation = rep(sample(urban, length(panelID), replace = T), each = n),
                 size = rep(sample(sizes, length(panelID), replace = T), each = n),
                 norm = round(runif(100)/10,2),
                 sales= round(rnorm(10,10,10),2),
                 Happiness = sample(10,10),
                 Sex = round(rnorm(10,0.75,0.3),2),
                 Age = sample(100,100),
                 Educ = round(rnorm(10,0.75,0.3),2))        
DT [, uniqueID := .I]                                                         # Creates a unique ID     
DT[DT == 0] <- NA 
DT$sales[DT$sales< 0] <- NA 
DT <- as.data.frame(DT)

setDT(DT)[,Mean_Sales_pergroup := mean(sales, na.rm=TRUE),  by=c("industry", "year")]
```

Now I want to compare how the `Mean_Sales_pergroup` differs per `industry` over the years, so I thought of trying:

```
table(DT$Mean_Sales_pergroup, DT$year)
```

But that gives me:

```
                   2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010
  2.11                0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
  2.18                0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
  2.61                2    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
  3.6775              0    0    0    0    4    0    0    0    0    0
  ...
  14.19               0    0    0    0    0    0    0    2    0    0
```

Which is of course anything but informative.

What could I do to get something like:

```
           2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010
Industry D  ..
Industry E
Industry F
```

EDIT:

@rg255's comment gives:

```
dcast(DT, industry ~ year, value.var = "Mean_Sales_pergroup")
Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'
   industry 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010
1:        D    1    1    5    5    3    4    1    1    6    1
2:        E    2    5    5    3    4    3    3    1    3    5
3:        F    1    6    2    3    4    7    5    2    4    4
```

Comment: I'm not sure of the numbers you expect to get out but does: `dcast(DT, industry ~ year, value.var = "Mean_Sales_pergroup")` do what you want/expect?

Comment: @rg255 Thanks for your comment! This is already a step in the right direction, but I guess I was hoping to see the means instead of the occurrences of the means.

Comment: That's what I had aimed for but working on the phone it wasnt easy to see/work out whether I'd succeeded:D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making unique rows then casting

```
dcast(unique(DT[, .(industry, year, Mean_Sales_pergroup)]), ... ~ year)
```

Gives the desired output

```
   industry  2001  2002   2003     2004    2005     2006     2007  2008
1:        D  2.61 4.260  6.204 9.650000 10.7050 8.625000 2.110000  2.61
2:        E 13.24 6.766  9.940 5.156667  3.6775 9.225000 4.606667 13.24
3:        F  2.61 8.000  ...
```

Comment: Very nice! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Because you have 0 or 1 unique instance of `Mean_Sales_pergroup` for 
each possible combination of `industry` and `year`, you could also 
solve it as follows:

```
dcast(DT, industry ~ year, fun = function(x) x[1], value.var = "Mean_Sales_pergroup")
```